Parent component is not being refreshed in Angular 17
I have a project with Angular 17 and Bootstrap 5.3.
I have a component that has 3 child components.
The first component gets the data, the second shows the results and the third one has a form to update an user. The second component has an EDIT button.
When the EDIT button is clicked, the parent componet should hide the first two components and the third one appear, but when I click the button, nothing happens.
I put some console.log around and I can see that there is data on the users-show-table component and on the service, but no data on the users-search.
<!-- users-edit.component.html -->
<div class="full-width" *ngIf="!editMode">
  <app-users-get-data
    (usersFetched)="onUsersFetched($event)"
    (submitPressed)="handleSubmitPressed($event)"
  >
  </app-users-get-data>
</div>

<div class="full-width" id="table" *ngIf="!editMode">
  <app-users-show-table 
    [users]="users" 
    [submitted]="submitted"
  >
  </app-users-show-table>
</div>

<div class="full-width" *ngIf="editMode">
  <app-users-edit-action></app-users-edit-action>
</div>

import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { iUserDTO } from '../../../models/iUserDTO';
import { EditCommunicationService } from '../../../services/user/edit-communication.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-edit',
  templateUrl: './users-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-edit.component.css']  <!-- Note: Corrected 'styleUrl' to 'styleUrls' -->
})
export class UsersEditComponent implements OnInit {
  users: iUserDTO[] | null = null;
  submitted: boolean = false;
  editMode: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private editCommunicationService: EditCommunicationService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit of users-edit');
    
    this.editCommunicationService.editModeChanged.subscribe((editMode: boolean) => {
      console.log('editMode ', editMode);
      this.editMode = editMode;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }

  onUsersFetched(users: iUserDTO[] | null) {
    this.users = users;
  }

  handleSubmitPressed(submitted: boolean) {
    this.submitted = submitted;
  }
}

<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="onEditUser(user)">{{ 'EDIT' | translate }}</button>

// users-show-table.component.ts
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { iUserDTO } from '../../../models/iUserDTO';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../../helpers/local-storage.service';
import { UserService } from '../../../services/user/user.service';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { LanguageChangeService } from '../../../services/language-change-service';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import { EditCommunicationService } from '../../../services/user/edit-communication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-show-table',
  templateUrl: './users-show-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-show-table.component.css']
})
export class UsersShowTableComponent implements OnInit {
  action: string = '';
  responseMessage: string = '';
  messageStatus: string = '';
  messageHeader: string = '';
  modalMessage: string = '';
  modalHeader: string = '';
  modalVisible: boolean = false;
  private modal: bootstrap.Modal | null = null;
  serviceError: string = '';
  showServiceError: boolean = false;
  

  @ViewChild('errorModal') modalElementRef!: ElementRef;

  @Input() users: iUserDTO[] | null = null;
  @Input() submitted: boolean = false; 

 
  showDeleteAlert: boolean = false;
  userToDelete: iUserDTO | null = null;

  constructor(
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private languageChangeService: LanguageChangeService,
    private editCommunicationService: EditCommunicationService
    ) 
    { 
      console.log('UsersShowTableComponent instanciado');
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.action = this.localStorageService.getData('action');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.modal = new bootstrap.Modal(this.modalElementRef.nativeElement);
  }  

  onEditUser(user: iUserDTO) {
    console.log('Editing user:', user);   
    this.editCommunicationService.notifyEditMode(true);    
  }

This is the service:

import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EditCommunicationService {
  public editModeChanged: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {}

  notifyEditMode(editMode: boolean) {
    console.log('On the service ', editMode);
    this.editModeChanged.emit(editMode);
  }
}


Right now this is a little hard to follow which is likely to reduce the number of answers you receive because most people are unlikely to spend a significant amount of time making sense of a question. This isn’t criticism, it’s feedback to try to increase the likelihood you get answers. In general you want to make it easy for answerers to understand your problem at a glance.

Thanks, changes made according of what you said

what's the code inside the component app-users-edit-action? I'm guessing this is the button that be clicked to trigger the event?

@Jairo issue not reproducible stackblitz please try replicating it and share back!

It tourns out that I have the crud functionality on a base component and this components are part of a structure:
 override onSearchClick(): void {    
    this.crudActionsVisibilityService.setSearchVisible();
    this.updateVisibility();    
    this.localStorageService.removeData('action');
    this.localStorageService.setData('action', 'search');     
  }
  
  override onDeleteClick(): void {    
    this.crudActionsVisibilityService.setSearchVisible();
    this.updateVisibility();    
    this.localStorageService.removeData('action');
    this.localStorageService.setData('action', 'delete');     
  }

  override onEditClick(): void {    
    this.crudActionsVisibilityService.setSearchVisible();
    this.updateVisibility();    
    this.localStorageService.removeData('action');
    this.localStorageService.setData('action', 'edit');     

Because several point to search who takes care of getting the information and presenting the results, the components user-delete and user-edit were of no use.
So the code was on the wrong parent component. Now it works.
It is better to keep on the documentation how the components comunicate with each other. Thank you for your comments.
